# In Django 1.6, how to find what database a model object is from?

Tags: django, multiple-databases

In Django, in a project using multiple databases and given a model object, how can I find out the name of the database (corresponding to the names used in `using` and configured in `settings.DATABASES`) the object is from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do: `<object>._state.db` to get the database the object is stored in.

[Here is the relevant source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/db/models/base.py#L310)

Also here is the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers)  (no very obvious though.. )

Answer (score 0):

My original answer was incorrect, but I've updated it using @karthikr's answer:

```
from django.conf import settings

m = MyModel.objects.get(...)
db = settings.DATABASES[m._state.db]
```

This gets the full database information dictionary from the settings.

Comment: Hi Joseph - I don't think the first approach you suggest is correct. The db from which an object comes isn't inherently related to its app_label.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. I was using a project of mine as a source and it looks like we defined our db routers to use app labels. @karthikr's answer is correct, and my code will get the specific db settings.